# What is the size of particles through which which white light is scattered?

Tags: optics, scattering

I know that the colour of light scattered depends on size of particles. Smallest particles scatter violet, a bit bigger particles scatter indigo... biggest particles scatter red(increasing order of VIBGYOR).

But when is white light scattered? Do we need particles of all sizes or the particles should be even smaller than particles which scatter violet or even bigger than particles which scatter red?

Comment: As per the answer referred to by @JohnRennie, when there are many particles close together then the intensity of the scattered light is more or less independent of the wavelength.

Comment: See, perhaps,  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_scattering   and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mie_scattering